# Where does the 1/2 come from in integral equation for magnetic moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, magnetic-moment

I saw that the formula for magnetic dipole moment is $$\mu=\frac{1}{2}\int\textbf{r}\times\textbf{j}\hspace{0.1cm}d^3r.$$
I understand the general intuition behind it. We are essentially summing up the "perpendicular quantity density" (which we define as the magnetic moment) caused by some current density $\textbf{j}$. What I don't understand is where the $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from. Is there another formula the magnetic moment is derived from, or is the fraction a result of tweaking theory to fit experiment?

Comment: area of a triangle is base times altitude divided by 2...

Comment: How's a magnetic moment related to a triangle?

Comment: The "area" is the area enclosed by the current, the magnetic moment is area times current. The "triangle" is fromed by the origin of your coordinate system in which the vectors $\mathbf{r}$ is defined and the infinitesimal tangent vectors of the loop, so that $d\mathbf {A} = \mathbf {r} \times d\mathbf {\ell}/2$.

Comment: Ah I see thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential vector is given by
$$\vec A(\vec r)={\mu_0\over 4\pi}\int {\vec j(\vec r\ \!')\over ||\vec r-\vec r\ \!'||}d^3\vec r\ \!'$$
If the currents are confined to a small region $r\ \!'\ll r$, the term ${1\over ||\vec r-\vec r\ \!'||}$ may be replaced by its Taylor expansion. At zero-th order, one gets
$$\vec A(\vec r)={\mu_0\over 4\pi r}\int {\vec j(\vec r\ \!')}d^3\vec r\ \!'$$
It can be shown that this integral vanishes. The first-order term is
$$\vec A(\vec r)={\mu\over 4\pi r}\times \Big[{1\over 2}\int \vec r\ \!'\times \vec j(\vec r\ \!')d^3\vec r\ \!'\Big]\times\vec\nabla{1\over r}$$
The magnetic moment is defined as the term inside the brakets. Finally, to first-order in $r\ \!'/r$,
$$\vec A(\vec r)={\mu_0\over 4\pi r^3}\vec m\times\vec r$$
With this choice of $\vec m$, the expansion of $\vec A$ is similar to the expansion of the electric potential $V(\vec r)$
$$\vec V(\vec r)={Q\over 4\pi\varepsilon_0r}+{\vec p.\vec r\over 4\pi\varepsilon_0r^3}+\ldots$$